# Creating table with 2 froeign keys not working in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I am trying to create 2 tables in MySQL with the below mentioned script but the second query fails with:

> Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint.

Is it because I am linking 2 columns in **emergency_contact_tbl** with single column in **userinfo** table?

How else could I create this relationship in the database?

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `userinfo` (
  `userid` INT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45),
  PRIMARY KEY (`userid`) )

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `emergency_contact_tbl` (
  `userid` INT NOT NULL ,
  `emergency_contact_personid` INT NOT NULL ,
  INDEX `emergency_contact_tbl_idx` (`userid` ASC, `emergency_contact_personid` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `emergency_contact_tbl_cons`
    FOREIGN KEY (`userid` , `emergency_contact_personid` )
    REFERENCES `userinfo` (`userid` , `userid` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use twice the same column in the `REFERENCES` clause.

What you should do is:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `emergency_contact_tbl` (
  `userid` INT NOT NULL ,
  `emergency_contact_personid` INT NOT NULL ,
  INDEX `emergency_contact_tbl_idx` (`userid` ASC, `emergency_contact_personid` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `emergency_contact_tbl_cons1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`userid`  )
    REFERENCES `userinfo` (`userid` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `emergency_contact_tbl_cons2`
    FOREIGN KEY (`emergency_contact_personid` )
    REFERENCES `userinfo` (`userid` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

Comment: Nor would it make sense to.  It's not the combination of those two columns which reference `userinfo`, but rather each column separately references `userinfo`.  What is weird here though, is the `ON DELETE CASCADE`. should that really be applied to both?

Comment: Well, I think that it depends on your data model and what do you plan to do if a record of `userinfo` is deleted. What I would do is to remove the `ON DELETE CASCADE` clause from both constraints and treat deletes programmatically... But as I said, it depends of your case.

Comment: Thanks, this works, but where can I get information like "You cannot use twice the same column in the REFERENCES clause" I didn't find it mentioned in SQL books?

Comment: Well... I'm not sure, but I think it shoud appear on the official docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Comment: @Rahul You can mention the same column in the `FOREIGN KEY` (but I don't think you can do it in the `REFERENCES`)- at least in Postgres: [SQl-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f7606)